# Choose whichever [one] you prefer

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

> Apple or banana, choose whichever you prefer.
>
> Apple or banana, choose whichever *one* you prefer.

If the options are only "Apple" and "Banana", which of the above phrases is correct or both are correct?

P.S. I found both phrases are used in formal writings: [whichever you prefer](https://ludwig.guru/s/whichever+you+prefer), [whichever one you prefer](https://ludwig.guru/s/whichever+one+you+prefer), hence the confusion.

Comment: This question is off-topic - there is no research indicated to show that the OP has checked if either are right or wrong.

Comment: @Astralbee Not anymore.

Comment: It makes no difference how many options there are. (If there were three or more, including _one_ would emphasise that the chooser may only take one!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple or banana, choose **whichever** you prefer. [pronoun]

Apple or banana, choose **whichever one** you prefer. [adjective]

Both are fine because whichever is a noun or an adjective.

[Merrian Webster - whichever](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whichever)